# Erro ao utilizar Collections.sort()

Tags: java, estrutura-de-dados

Estudando coleções, fui tentar usar o seguinte exemplo no Eclipse:

```
public class TestaLista {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List <Conta> list = new ArrayList<Conta>();

        Conta cc1 = new ContaCorrente();
        cc1.setNumero(10);

        Conta cc2 = new ContaCorrente();
        cc2.setNumero(5);

        Conta cc3 = new ContaCorrente();
        cc3.setNumero(2);


        list.add(cc1);
        list.add(cc2);
        list.add(cc3);

        System.out.println(list);
        Collections.sort(list);
        System.out.println("------------");
        System.out.println(list);

    }

}
```

A minha classe `ContaCorrente` é filha de Conta e implementa a classe `Comparable`. Porém, ao utilizar o método `sort()` de `Collections`, recebo a mensagem de erro:

> The method sort(List) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List).

Não consigo encontrar o problema no código. Alguém ajuda?

---

Classe Conta:

```
public abstract class Conta  {
    protected double saldo;
    protected int numero;
    private int agencia;
    private String nome;

    public double getSaldo() {
        return saldo;
    }

    public void deposita(double valor) {
        if (valor > 0) {
            this.saldo += valor;
        } else {
            throw new ValorInvalidoException(valor);
        }
        System.out.println("Fim do deposita");
    }

    public void saca(double valor) {
        this.saldo -= valor;
    }

    public abstract void atualiza(double taxaSelic);

    public int getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(int numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    public int getAgencia() {
        return agencia;
    }

    public void setAgencia(int agencia) {
        this.agencia = agencia;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof Conta)){
            return false;
        }
        Conta c = (Conta)obj;
        return this.numero == c.numero || this.nome.equals(c.nome);
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return "Conta de número " + this.numero;
    }

}
```

Comment: Tem como postar (as partes relevantes) da classe `ContaCorrente`?

Comment: Implemente a interface `Comparable` na Classe `Conta` e defina o método de comparação. O seguinte link irá lhe ajudar: http://blog.caelum.com.br/ordenando-colecoes-com-comparable-e-comparator/

Comment: @jbueno feito nas respostas

Comment: Icaro, clique em [edit] quando for adicionar informações no seu post. Não adicione respostas pra isso.

Comment: Tudo bem, obrigado pela dica. Sou novo nisso xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para o objeto ser ordenado na lista é necessário 2 coisas:

- O objeto implementar `Comparable<X>`, onde `X` é o tipo dos objetos a serem comparados (no seu caso, `Conta`).
- O objeto sobrescrever a função `compareTo()` do `Comparable`.

Para sobrescrever o método `compareTo()` do `Comparable`, você tem que implementar uma forma de avaliar quando um objeto é maior ou menor que outro. Por exemplo:

```
@Override 
public int compareTo(Conta conta) {
  if (conta.saldo == this.saldo) return 0;
  if (conta.saldo < this.saldo) return 1;
  /*if (conta.saldo > this.saldo)*/ return -1;
}
```

Note que o método deve retornar **0 se os objetos são iguais**, **1 quando o objeto `this` é maior** que o objeto enviado por parâmetro e **-1 quando o objeto `this` é menor** que o objeto enviado por parâmetro.

Comment: Comentei o último if no método `compareTo` porque senão o compilador reclamaria que o método pode não retornar um valor. Além disso, esse último if é desnecessário, vez que se os dois acima são falsos, então ele obrigatoriamente seria sempre verdadeiro.

Comment: Boa observacao @Vitor Stafusa

Answer (score 0):

O problema provavelmente é causado porque `ContaCorrente` implementa `Comparable`, mas `Conta` não. E no seu código você está instânciando uma lista de contas( ao invés de contas correntes):

```
List<Conta> list = new ArrayList<Conta>();
```

Tente trocar o código acima para:

```
List<ContaCorrente> list = new ArrayList<ContaCorrente>();
```

Comment: Tentei, mas o erro continua...

Comment: @icarobuzz Nesse caso poste os fontes das classes Conta e ContaCorrente.

Comment: feito nas respostas.

Comment: @icarobuzz É para colocar o fonte na pergunta, não como resposta. Clique em 'remover' na parte inferior da sua resposta e em seguida clique em 'editar' na parte inferior da sua pergunta.

Comment: @icarobuzz vamos conversar mais sobre esta pergunta [neste](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47830/discussao-pergunta-erro-ao-utilizar-collections-sort) chat.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema. Fiz a classe `ContaCorrente` implementar `Comparable` e corrigi o retorno do método `compareTo()`, que retorna -1 caso o número da conta passada por argumento seja maior, +1 se for menor e zero se forem iguais. No método `main` a lista deve ser do tipo `ContaCorrente` para evitar erros de compilação. Novamente, desculpem pela bagunça.

Answer (score 0):

Realizei alguns testes e funcionou!

Com o exemplo citado acima, a lista já está organizada!

Então não haverá mudança na lista:

> [Conta de número 10, Conta de número 5, Conta de número 2]
>
> [Conta de número 10, Conta de número 5, Conta de número 2]

A Implementação do seu `compareTo` ordena do maior para ao menor:

```
        public int compareTo(Conta o) {

            if(this.numero > o.numero){
                return -1;
            }
            if (this.numero < o.numero) {
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

Caso queira ordenar do maior para o menor, apenas inverta os valores:

```
    public int compareTo(Conta o) {
        if(this.numero > o.numero){
            return 1;
        }
        if (this.numero < o.numero) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

**Observação**: Existe uma forma mais simples de implementar o método `compareTo` quando se compara `int`!

Levando em consideração que ele vai retornar um número positivo , ou negativo, tente o seguinte:

```
            public int compareTo(Conta o) {
            // ordena do maior para o menor
//          return (o.numero - this.numero); 
            // ordena do menor para o maior
            return ( this.numero - o.numero ); 
        }
```

[Clique aqui para ver o código rodando no Ideone!](http://ideone.com/8wdBlE)